# Can I make Tmux tell Vim when its pane loses focus?

Tags: vim, tmux

I use Vim and Bash side-by-side in Tmux. I have Vim configured to autosave files as I switch between them, but I'd really like it to autosave when I switch to the Bash pane.

Is there a way to get Tmux to send some kind of code to Vim when its pane loses focus?

Answer (score 7):

This is probably best done using `vim`'s client-server model. There's some good guidance about using it in `:help remote.txt`.

Firstly, you'll need a `vim` client compiled with the `+clientserver` option. If your distribution doesn't package it this way, get the source (through `apt-get source`, `abs`, et al) and add that option.

Once that's done, you'll need to rebind your keys in `tmux` so that when you change windows it also sends something like the following to the active window:

```
vim --servername foo --remote-send '<C-\><C-N>:w<CR>'
```

Something like the following should work (not tested):

```
bind-key 0 run-shell "vim --servername foo --remote-send '<C-\><C-N>:w<CR>'" \; select-window -t :0
```

Comment: That's a good direction, but there are too many ways to switch panes.  I might `select-pane`, `last-pane`, `swap-pane`, or even click a pane.  There are just as many ways to switch to a different window.  I can't rebind every possible way to activate a different pane.  I'm looking, then, for a way to get commands to run every time I activate a pane.  Perhaps that's not possible in `tmux`.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else has already done this work for you in a vim plugin - https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim

From the README:

> (Vit)ality is a plugin that makes (V)im play nicely with (i)Term 2 and (t)mux.

If you're using vim and tmux together you might also be interested in the [vimux](https://github.com/benmills/vimux) plugin.

> By default when you call RunVimTmuxCommand vimux will create a 20% tall horizontal pane under your current tmux pane and execute a command in it without losing focus of vim. Once that pane exists whenever you call RunVimTmuxCommand again the command will be executed in that pane.

Think re-running tests frequently.

Comment: Actually, that's not what Vitality does.  Vitality maps iTerm's focus lost/gained codes—which trigger when you change GUI windows—into Vim's `FocusLost`/`Gained` events, but it doesn't notice if you change tmux windows.

Comment: @Peeja: ah, ok. I misread it, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: vitality.vim now does this with a fork of tmux: https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim/issues/2 https://github.com/aaronjensen/tmux